# Inverse problem can't solve it,:$2^{m+1}+1\mid 3^{2^{m}}+1$,when$2^{m+1}+1$ is prime number,

Tags: number-theory

> Let $m$ be a possitive natural number, and $2^{m+1}+1$ is prime number,
>
> show that:$2^{m+1}+1\mid 3^{2^{m}}+1$.

This  question inverse problem I can solve it, see this links[mathlinks](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h619448p3697293)

Comment: Hint: Fermat's little theorem

Comment: Hello,How use Fermat's little theorem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $p=2^{m+1}+1$. We want to show that
$$p|3^{\frac{p-1}2}+1$$

Little Fermat's theorem says that
$$p\mid 3^{p-1}-1=(3^{\frac{p-1}2}+1)(3^{\frac{p-1}2}-1)$$
so it suffices to show that $p$ does not divide $3^{\frac{p-1}2}-1$, that is, $2^{m+1}+1$ does not divide $3^{2^m}-1$.

Suppose now that $m+1$ has an odd prime divisor $q$, $m+1=qk$. Then $2^{qk}+1$ is a multiple of $2^k+1$, so is composite. Hence, $m+1$ has no odd prime divisors, that is, $m=2^r-1$. So we must show that $2^{2^r}+1$ does not divide $3^{2^{2^r-1}}-1$.

The group $\Bbb Z_{p}^\times$ is cyclic with $2^{2^r}$ elements, so it suffices to show that $3$ is not a square in this group.

Now, we apply the law of quadratic reciprocity:
$$\left(\frac p3\right)\left(\frac 3p\right)=(-1)^{2^m}=1$$ 
that is, $3$ is a square mod $p$ iff $p$ is a square mod $3$, that is, iff $p\equiv 1\pmod 3$. But $p-1$ is a power of two, which is not certainly a multiple of $3$. This solves the problem.

Comment: can you with out quadratic reciprocity?